# Boost acceptor accepts two times per incomming connection and makes two threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, tcp, boost-asio

I'm working ong a TCP server and i'm using the boost library for the tcp and socket functinality. I'm also using boost for threading. The server works but when i connect a client to the server the server creates two threads instead of one. I have a console print just after the accepting of a connection and this printline is seen two times per connection. For each connection a new thread will be made with a function that handles the connection. I have made a class GlobalControll that sets up the server and handles the connections.  My question is why two threads are created per connection? Since it should wait in for a new connection after with the accept function.

Bellow is the constructor function where i think the problem occurs.

```
GlobalControl::GlobalControl(){

cout << "Setting up a server with the default port (" << PORTNUMBER << ")" << endl;

// Protocol and port
 boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), PORTNUMBER);   

 // Create acceptor
 boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, endpoint);   

 // Create socket
 boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service); 

 for(;;){

     // Create socket
     SmartSocket sock(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(io_service));

     // Waiting for client
     acceptor.accept(*sock);
     cout << "Client connected" << endl;
     boost::thread t(InitHandler, sock); 
     Sleep(1);
 };  
};
```

The Inithandler function that each thread runs is the following function:

```
    // Global function that each thread wil run
    void InitHandler(SmartSocket sock){

    int result = -1;
    byte RecvData[DataGenerator::SHA256BYTESIZE];
    DataGenerator DatGen;

       try
       {
            bool pending = true;
            while(pending)
           {
            // Generate a new vector
            DatGen.GenerateInputData();

            // Send vector
            boost::asio::write(*sock, boost::asio::buffer(DatGen.digest, sizeof(DatGen.digest)));

            // Make sure that the RecvData variable is clear
            CleanData(RecvData, DataGenerator::SHA256BYTESIZE);

            // Recieve data back from client
            boost::asio::read(*sock, boost::asio::buffer(RecvData, DataGenerator::SHA256BYTESIZE));

            // Compare input vector with recieved data from client
            result = memcmp (DatGen.digest, RecvData, sizeof(DataGenerator::SHA256BYTESIZE));

            if(result != 0){
                cout << "Error found" << endl;
            };


        }
   }
           catch (std::exception& e){
         // std::cout << "Exception in thread: " << e.what() << std::endl;
       }
    };
```

If anyone could help me or give me a tip on this problem that would be great! Many thanks in advance.

Comment: So "Clien connected" is printed twice, even when you only connect one client?

Comment: Thanks for the commend and yes it is. So te for loop does two iterations per connection.

Comment: Just checked with the debugger and there are two threads created. Checked the id's of the threads and they are unique.

Comment: what's the socket for outside of the `for` loop?

Comment: I would suggest using async_accept and calling io_service.run() somewhere

Comment: Additionally a thread pool based approach is better.  Take a look at the HTTP Server 3 example in the asio docs. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/http/server3/server.cpp

Comment: Your problem may actually be occurring due to not assigning an address to the endpoint.

Comment: @Pete its listening socket, it can listen without assigning (so listen any address)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Didn't connect the client socket to the server socket the right way. The code of the server (in this thread) wasn't the problem. Called the connect function two times in a weird way in the client.

Fixed the problem by just calling connect after resolving the server socket, see below: (code of resolving the server socket is ommitted).

```
    tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    socket.connect(*iterator);
```

Thanks for all the comments.